# Apple TV gamepad buttons not triggering when I press them in the simulator

Tags: tvos, simulator, gamepad

I am experiencing a problem in the Apple TV simulator.  I have Xcode 9.4 and am using a Nimbus wireless controller.  I have a menu screen for a game which does not register button clicks on the extended gamepad.  The simulator sees the sticks and dpad and registers that when I use them but none of the buttons work.  Here is the code I have.  Here is the code.  Could someone please review this and tell me why they think this does not work?  Thanks, Greg

```
import UIKit
import GameController

class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupControllerObservers()
    connectControllers()
}

func setupControllerObservers() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(connectControllers), name: NSNotification.Name.GCControllerDidConnect, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(controllerDisconnected), name: NSNotification.Name.GCControllerDidDisconnect, object: nil)

}

@objc func connectControllers() {
    for controller in GCController.controllers() {
        if (controller.extendedGamepad != nil && controller.playerIndex == .indexUnset) {
            controller.playerIndex = .index1
            controller.extendedGamepad?.valueChangedHandler = nil
            setUpExtendedController(controller: controller)
        } else if (controller.gamepad != nil && controller.playerIndex == .indexUnset) {
            controller.playerIndex = .index1
            controller.gamepad?.valueChangedHandler = nil
            setUpStandardController(controller: controller)
        }
    }
}

enum stick {
    case dPad
    case leftThumbStick
    case rightThumbStick
}

enum direction {
    case up
    case down
    case left
    case right
}

enum button {
    case a
    case b
    case x
    case y
    case leftShoulder
    case leftTrigger
    case rightShoulder
    case rightTrigger
}

func move(whichStick: stick, whichDirection: direction) {
    print("moved")
}

func pressed(whichButton: button) {
    print("pressed")
}

func setUpExtendedController(controller:GCController) {
    controller.extendedGamepad?.valueChangedHandler = {
        (gamepad: GCExtendedGamepad, element: GCControllerElement) in

        if (gamepad.buttonA.isPressed) {
            print("tseting  button a pressed")
            self.pressed(whichButton: button.a)
        }

        if (gamepad.buttonX.isPressed) {
            self.pressed(whichButton: button.x)
        }

        if (gamepad.buttonY.isPressed) {
            self.pressed(whichButton: button.y)
        }

        if (gamepad.rightShoulder.isPressed) {
            self.pressed(whichButton: button.rightShoulder)
        }

        if (gamepad.rightTrigger.isPressed) {
            self.pressed(whichButton: button.rightTrigger)
        }

        if (gamepad.leftShoulder.isPressed) {
            self.pressed(whichButton: button.leftShoulder)
        }

        if (gamepad.leftTrigger.isPressed) {
            self.pressed(whichButton: button.leftTrigger)
        }

        if (gamepad.leftThumbstick == element) {
            if (gamepad.leftThumbstick.up.value > 0.2) {
                self.move(whichStick: stick.leftThumbStick, whichDirection: direction.up)
            } else if (gamepad.leftThumbstick.left.value > 0.2) {
                self.move(whichStick: stick.leftThumbStick, whichDirection: direction.left)
            } else if (gamepad.leftThumbstick.down.value > 0.2) {
                self.move(whichStick: stick.leftThumbStick, whichDirection: direction.down)
            } else if (gamepad.leftThumbstick.right.value > 0.2) {
                self.move(whichStick: stick.leftThumbStick, whichDirection: direction.right)
            }
        } else if (gamepad.dpad == element) {
            if (gamepad.dpad.down.isPressed == true) {
                self.move(whichStick: stick.dPad, whichDirection: direction.down)
            } else if (gamepad.dpad.left.isPressed == true) {
                self.move(whichStick: stick.dPad, whichDirection: direction.left)
            } else if (gamepad.dpad.right.isPressed == true) {
                self.move(whichStick: stick.dPad, whichDirection: direction.right)
            } else if (gamepad.dpad.up.isPressed == true) {
                self.move(whichStick: stick.dPad, whichDirection: direction.up)
            }
        } else if (gamepad.rightThumbstick == element) {
            if (gamepad.leftThumbstick.up.value > 0.2) {
                self.move(whichStick: stick.rightThumbStick, whichDirection: direction.up)
            } else if (gamepad.leftThumbstick.left.value > 0.2) {
                self.move(whichStick: stick.rightThumbStick, whichDirection: direction.left)
            } else if (gamepad.leftThumbstick.down.value > 0.2) {
                self.move(whichStick: stick.rightThumbStick, whichDirection: direction.down)
            } else if (gamepad.leftThumbstick.right.value > 0.2) {
                self.move(whichStick: stick.rightThumbStick, whichDirection: direction.right)
            }
        }

    }
}

func setUpStandardController(controller:GCController) {
    controller.gamepad?.valueChangedHandler = {
        (gamepad: GCGamepad, element:GCControllerElement) in

        if (gamepad.dpad == element) {
            if (gamepad.dpad.down.isPressed == true) {
                self.move(whichStick: stick.dPad, whichDirection: direction.down)
            } else if (gamepad.dpad.left.isPressed == true) {
                self.move(whichStick: stick.dPad, whichDirection: direction.left)
            } else if (gamepad.dpad.right.isPressed == true) {
                self.move(whichStick: stick.dPad, whichDirection: direction.right)
            } else if (gamepad.dpad.up.isPressed == true) {
                self.move(whichStick: stick.dPad, whichDirection: direction.up)
            }
        } else if (gamepad.buttonA == element) {
            self.pressed(whichButton: button.a)
            //} else if (gamepad.buttonB == element) {
            //    self.pressed(whichButton: button.b)
        } else if (gamepad.buttonX == element) {
            self.pressed(whichButton: button.x)
        } else if (gamepad.buttonY == element) {
            self.pressed(whichButton: button.y)
        } else if (gamepad.rightShoulder == element) {
            self.pressed(whichButton: button.rightShoulder)
        } else if (gamepad.leftShoulder == element) {
            self.pressed(whichButton: button.leftShoulder)
        }
    }
}


@objc func controllerDisconnected() {

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out my problem.  I needed to use buttonA == element instead of buttonA.isPressed.

Answer (score 0):

To add to this, the tvOS simulator won’t recognize the GCMicroGamepad.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamecontroller/gccontroller/1627772-microgamepad

It will only recognize the extended gamepad using a physical MFi device paired with your Mac.

To test the GCMicroGamepad, you need to use Test Flight with a physical Apple TV.

If you enable the GCMicroGamepad for tvOS, the physical Apple TV will automatically recognize the Siri Remote as a micro gamepad. It doesn’t work on the tvOS simulator.